# Redirect to login page if user not logged in but don't redirect googlebot

Tags: wordpress, authentication, googlebot

How can i this? You cannot access the site without a member, but google bot can enter. How can I do this? You cannot access the site without a member, but Google bot can enter. I tried to create a variable and exclude the IP number, but I failed.

Comment: Try to add honeypoint, hide link in robots.txt etc. I recommend try to play with plugin All In one WP Security(it has build in tools for it).

Answer (score 1):

It would be best to test by [using reverse DNS lookup](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/80553) since [User Agent can be spoofed](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1061943?hl=en). PHP makes it pretty easy, here's a sample test:

```
// $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; // Use to check the visitor IP
$ip = '66.249.66.1'; // Sample Google IP from their docs
$host_name = gethostbyaddr($ip);
$is_google = strpos($host_name, 'google') !== false ? 'is' : 'is <b>NOT</b>';

echo "<p>$host_name</p>";

echo  "<p>IP Address $is_google Google</p>";
```

Now we can check if the user is logged in and if they are not a google bot. Using the WordPress `template_redirect` hook [is recommended](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/template_redirect). Add this to your `functions.php` theme file:

```
/**
 * Redirect the user to login if they are not logged in and not a google bot
 */
function redirect_not_logged_in_not_google() {
    $host_name = gethostbyaddr($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
    if( strpos($host_name, 'google') === false && !is_user_logged_in() ) {
        wp_redirect( home_url( '/login/' ) );
        die;
    }
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'redirect_not_logged_in_not_google' );
```

Comment: I tried your code but it didn't work. Redirected to Google IP login page. https://resmim.net/f/pzBW5C.png?v=10201914210403000300

Comment: So it looks like you have both the sample testing code and `redirect_not_logged_in_not_google()` function/action in your `functions.php`. If you want to test it live in the WordPress theme, you'll have to change `$host_name = gethostbyaddr($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);` to `$host_name = gethostbyaddr('66.249.66.1');` where `'66.249.66.1'` is the sample Google IP address. You were currently still be redirected to the `/login` page because where you are viewing your site from is not Google. ;-)